# Solution of $\int \frac{1}{x^2 \sqrt{x^2+9}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

I'm new of the site. I must solve this exercise:

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2 \sqrt{x^2+9}}\,dx$$

I tried every substitution, but I didn't reach that I want.
Can you help me, please?

Comment: Did you take $x = 3 \cosh \alpha$?

Comment: Please be specific about what you have tried. You cannot have tried every posible substitution, for there are infinitely many! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach.

Assuming that $x\geq b>0. $ You may write
$$
\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{x^2 \sqrt{x^2+9}}dx &=\int \frac{1}{x^2 \sqrt{1+\frac{9}{x^2}}}\frac{dx}{x}\\\\
&=-\int \frac{u}{\sqrt{1+9u^2}}\:du\\\\
&=-\frac19\sqrt{1+9u^2}\\\\
&=-\frac19\frac{\sqrt{x^2+9}}{x},
\end{align}
$$
the case $x\leq a<0 $ is similar.

Comment: On the RHS of your first equation, that should be an $x^3$ on the outside of the square root, not $x^2$.  See Mike's solution.

Comment: @user3440448 Please, look carefully you will see that you have $x^2$ in front of the radical but also $x$ back to it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I see it now.  I'm gonna leave this comments here in case anyone else missed it as I did.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Let $x = 3\tan(u).$ Therefore $\frac{dx}{du} = 3\sec^2{u} \implies dx=3\sec^2{u}\ du$. So, our integral becomes

$$\int\frac{3\sec^2{u}}{9\tan^2(u)\sqrt{9\tan^2(u)+9}}du= \int\frac{\sec^2{u}}{9\tan^2(u)\sqrt{\tan^2(u)+1}}du$$

$$=\int\frac{\sec{u}}{9\tan^2(u)}du$$
$$=\frac{1}{9}\int\frac{\sec{u}\cos^{2}(u)}{\sin^2(u)}du$$
$$=\frac{1}{9}\int\frac{\cos(u)}{\sin^2(u)}du.$$
$$=\frac{1}{9}\int\frac{1}{\sin^2(u)}d(\sin{u})$$
$$=\frac{1}{9}\int\sin^{-2}(u)d(\sin{u})$$
$$=\frac{1}{9}\left[-\sin^{-1}(u)\right]+C$$

Now we must return our expression in terms of $x$. That is, we wish to find the value of $\sin^{-1}(u)$ in terms of $x$. Note that this is **not** sine inverse - it is "sin(u) to the power of -1". Recall that:

$$ x = 3\tan{u} \implies \tan{u} = \frac{x}{3}.$$

Assume that $0 < u < \frac{\pi}{2}$ if you draw a right angled triangle you will notice that the opposite side is $x$ and the adjacent side is $3$. By Pythagoras's Theorem the hypotenuse is therefore $\sqrt{x^{2}+9}$. Therefore

$$\sin{u} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+9}}.$$

Thus, our answer is

$$\frac{1}{9}\left[-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+9}}\right]^{-1}+C = -\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+9}}{9x} +C .$$

Comment: Thanks, but now, calculating, I have $\frac{1}{9 \operatorname{sin} \operatorname{arctg} \frac{x}{3}}$. The solution in the book is $-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+9}}{9x}$.

Comment: @userNew. Ok. I will edit my post and complete the solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

Either one of the substitutions

- [$x=3\tan(t)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution)
- [$x=3\sinh(t)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicSubstitution.html)
- [$\sqrt{x^2+9}-x=t$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution)

should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think Olivier had the right idea, but his substitution went awry.  Similar to how he started.

$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+9}}=\int\frac{dx}{x^3\sqrt{1+9x^{-2}}}$$

Now substitute

$$u=1+9x^{-2},du=-18x^{-3}dx$$

$$-\frac1{18}\int u^{-1/2}du=-\frac19u^{1/2}+C=-\frac19\sqrt{1+9x^{-2}}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Convert to $1\over x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}$ form first.